# Calling Python Eve from an Flask application leads to weird errors

Tags: python, flask, eve

I've created an Eve API which is being called from an Flask Application using SSL protected traffic. 
The application itself should be working nevertheless an error occurs when Eve tries to handle the incoming requests.

```
Eve==0.6.4
Flask==0.10.1



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eve/flaskapp.py", line 968, in __call__
    return super(Eve, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1539, in handle_user_exception
    return self.handle_http_exception(e)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1495, in handle_http_exception
    handler = self._find_error_handler(e)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1476, in _find_error_handler
    .get(code))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/eve-oauth2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1465, in find_handler
    handler = handler_map.get(cls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in this case it was in incompatibility between the libraries, no idea why. 
Upgrade Eve and Flask via pip (`pip install --upgrade flask` and `pip install --upgrade eve`) and it works again.